# Vector Addition on a TI-84?

Tags: linear-algebra

So my Linear Algebra textbook is talking about how to do vector addition, and has this image on the side as an example of what it might look like when done on a calculator -- but then refers you to their website for instructions on how to actually do it. Problem is I can't find the info they're talking about; I guess it's outdated or something. I googled around how to do vector addition on a TI-84 (the kind of calculator I have), but don't see anything with "VECTOR: U" or anything similar like in the image. So how do I do this?

[image]

Comment: You do it *sans calculator*!

Comment: Obviously...but I want to learn how to do it both ways...which is obviously what my book is trying to teach me or they wouldn't have included the image. -_-

Comment: I'm not familiar with the way they're doing it as depicted above, but if you know how to store matrices on the TI, then your matrix variables can be summed in the usual way.